# metrics on complex vector bundles..

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $E$ be a complex vector bundle with $J$. Let $g_0, g_1$ be two $J$-invariant metric fiberwise.

If $g_0$ and $g_1$ give the same orientation on each fiber, then can we construct a complex bundle isomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi^* g_1 = g_0$ ?

--- It is not easy for me to check $\phi$ is $J$-invariant.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I don't think so. If $\phi^*g_1 = g_0$ then the curvatures of the metrics are related by $\Theta_{g_0} = \phi^* \Theta_{g_1}$, and it shouldn't be hard to find two metrics whose curvatures are not compatible.

Comment: This is not about diffeomorphisms. The bundle morphism $\phi$ is the identity on the level of the base manifold.



Comment: I think this is very easy, unless you say that there should also be a connection on $E$ be preserved by the isomorphism.

Comment: In general one cannot speak about the curvature of the metric: it's not unique.

Comment: Right, I'm sorry. Every time I see a metric I fix a connection in my head (Chern or L-C).

Answer (score 3):

Well, since nobody closed the question...

First, a metric *does not* define an orientation (but a complex structure does).

The bundle morphism you are looking for can be constructed as follows: take the unique automorphism of E such that $g_1(X,Y)=g_0(AX,Y)$ for all X,Y in the same fibre. Then $A$ is symmetric wrt $g_0$ and commutes with $J$. The unique positive definite square root, say $B$, of $A^{-1}$ is a bundle morphism which commutes with $J$ and satisfies $B^*g_0=g_1$.